# Polynomial Function Equation

Tags: functions, polynomials

I am having some trouble with a problem. Thanks in advance to anyone who answers.

Find a and b if $4x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + 6x + 1 = |P(x)|^2$

I have been staring at this problem for quite some time, and I can't seem to come up with anything useful.

Comment: What is $|P(x)|^2$?

Comment: Does $P(x)$ refer to the original quartic equation?

Comment: I believe P(x) represents the polynomial. As for the Quartic Equation, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:$$P(x)=px^2+qx+r$$$$\therefore |P(x)|=|px^2+qx+r|=\sqrt{(px^2+qx+r)^2}$$$$\therefore |P(x)|^2=(px^2+qx+r)^2=p^2x^4+2pqx^3+(2pr+q^2)x^2+2qrx+r^2$$Now just compare coefficients to solve this problem

Comment: Thank you very much! I do have one question, Did you chose the form px^2+qx+r so that it would result in a fourth degree variable when the power of 2 is applied to it?

Comment: Yes - we want (something)^2 to result in a quartic equation. So the "something" has to be a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $P(x) = \pm 2x^2+cx \pm 1$. Can you finish the rest?

Comment: I am trying to understand this, but... I can't. Why did you equalize P(x) to ±2x2+cx±1 ?

Comment: To get $4x^2$, you need to square $\pm 2x^2$; to get the $1$ you need to square $\pm1$. Is this making things better ?

Answer (score 0):

Expand the right hand side, simplify everything and compare.
You get: 
a=12
b=13
c=3

Answer (score 0):

The square of something is the same as the square of its absolute value, so you can disregard the absolute values sign.  You are given that the square of $P(x)$ is a quartic, so $P(x)$ is a quadratic.  The hand crank approach is to write $P(x)=dx^2+ex+f$, then $P(x)^2=$something and compare like terms.  The $4x^4$ will come from $(dx^2)^2$, so what can $d$ be?  The $+1$ will come from $f^2$, so what can $f$ be?  The $6x$ term can be used with what you know to evaluate $e$.  Square it and you are done. Don't forget that there is a sign ambiguity.